# How to resolve the relative path of a document URL in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am opening a word document in my MVC AngularJS web app by providing the Url as follow

var docUrl = "/Documents/Schedule Draft.docx";

window.location.assign(docUrl);

In Dev mode document is opening fine but when i deploy to the live environment it is messing up the deployed root folder.

e.g. my live app address is
http://development.software.co.uk/Modules/Management/#/application

and after clicking the document button the url changes to follow
http://development.software.co.uk/Documents/Schedule%20Draft.docx

From above 2 URL's, it is clear that Modules/Management/ folders are being removed by the document url.

Can anyone tell me how I can rectify this issue

P.S. I don't want to hard code the /Modules/Management/ part as this is just the test site while actual live site folder structure is different than this one.